# Visual Studio Значение "maxValue" должно быть больше нуля

Tags: c#

Весь код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainPage.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random random = new Random();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddEnemy();
    }

    private void AddEnemy()
    {   
        ContentControl enemy=new ContentControl();
        enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
        AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 1),
            random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 1), "(Canvas.Top)");
        playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
    }

    private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = from,
            To = to,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6))),
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }


}
```

}

При запуске ошибка

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Значение "maxValue" должно быть больше нуля.'
```

В свойствах высота/ширина установлены на авто.

[image: Свойства]

Значения переменных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Контрол и его настройки тут ни при чем. Вы в один из вызовов Random.Next(maxValue) отдаете отрицательное значение или 0.

Comment: @PashaPash но если установить Height например, 300, то все отлично работает. Значит, причина все таки в нем?

Comment: Причина в том, у что вас `(int)playArea.ActualHeight - 1` <= `0`. Почему это так - из скрина в вопросе непонятно :)

Comment: Составьте [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Сейчас мы не можем проверить Ваш код, т.к. у нас нет `playArea`. Проверьте значения свойств в режиме отладки и впишите их непосредственно в код.

Comment: добавил весь код и значения переменных

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Вам уже написали, что у вас проблема в `random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 1)`. Когда вы задаете `ActualHeight` больше 1, то `random.Next()` проходит корректно, т.к. параметр больше 0, иначе он становится меньше или равен 0 , что и вызывает ошибку. Почему у вас так рандом рассчитывается - это уже другой вопрос.